# Is it possible to set an email signature in Office 365 Outlook to a user via API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook, office365

I am developing an application in ASP .Net MVC. I have Azure Active Directory authorization in it. Is it possible to set an email signature in Office 365 Outlook for domain users via API? My googling skills did not allow me to find any information about this. Before that, I used Google Workspace and it was possible. Now I'm in a situation where I have to transfer some things from Google API to Office 365, and I can't see anything about the footer.